# Is it possible to implement coroutine with threads?

Tags: c++

All in title. Since coroutine just need a sort of EIP memory, and thread provides that, is it possible to do it? That's way to have a highly portable coroutine library.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "coroutine" in this context?

Comment: is the question whether you can emulate co-operative multi-tasking with pre-emptive threads? The answer is yes if that's the question, but that would just be inefficient.

Comment: I mean by coroutine the C++20 ones or Python ones, for example. As a function that can return and save all it's variables and current line of code to be continued afterhands.

Comment: All a coroutine is, in-effect, is a resumable function. It is possible to implement this in a library -- and in fact, several already exist for C++ ([Boost.Coroutine](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/coroutine/doc/html/index.html) comes to mind). However there is a lot that the *compiler* can do better with coroutines at the language level that can't be done in a library can (e.g. inlining, saving state to the stack rather than the heap based on a heuristic, etc). AFAIK, none of this requires threads -- though I'm sure it _could be done_ with them

Comment: When you say "_implement_", do you mean that you want to create a coroutine library yourself and to not `#include <coroutine>` like in [this example](https://godbolt.org/z/hvc79653b) (copied from cppreference)?

Comment: @Human-Compiler: To persist state on the stack, you need stack space that doesn't go away when the routine suspends.  That means stack switching... and threads provide stack switching in a portable way.

Comment: It's more a theoric question than a practical one. I know it's possible in ASM but without it ? @Ted Lyngmo Yes, without ASM if possible

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo Yes I want to do that. C++20 coroutines resources are hard to find on the net for now. Plus, I was just thinking about the idea...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement coroutines / generators based on threads or even fibers. But they would be less performant compared to implementations like msvc or gcc provide.

I implemented coroutines that way (no threads, but fibers) in delphi. You need to estimate how much stack-memory do you need, you need to create those threads (which is heavy...).

So you should avoid that.